# GameObject not Spawining

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a tetris game with unity but this code is not spawning my tetrimino. I have assigned my gameobjects to the group[] array.

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] group;
    void start(){
        SpawnNext ();
    }
    void SpawnNext(){
        Instantiate(group[Random.Range(0,group.Length)],new Vector2(5.0f,10.0f),Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: For questions that are clearly typos, please vote to close under the reason Off Topic > Typo/Not Reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not spawning because you used lower-case `s` in `start`. This should be `Start` not `start`. Please fix that and your object should now start spawning.

```
public class Spawner1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] group;
    void Start(){
        SpawnNext ();
    }

    void SpawnNext(){
        Instantiate(group[Random.Range(0,group.Length)],new Vector2(5.0f,10.0f),Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```